# python regex - extract value from string

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I would like to know how can I get from a string and using reg expressions all values until the comma starting from the end. See below example, I would like to get the value `"CA 0.810"` into a variable:

```
prue ="VA=-0.850,0.800;CA=-0.863,0.800;SP=-0.860,0.810;MO=-0.860,0.810;SUN=MO -0.850,CA 0.810"
```

So far, I have the below code:

```
test = re.findall('([0-9]+)$',prue)
print test
```

However, I only get below output:

```
['810']
```

Could you please advise how can I get `"CA 0.810"` into the `test` variable?

Comment: Split with a comma and get the last item.

Comment: Any reason for a regex? Why not just `prue.rpartition(',')[2]` ?

Comment: Agree with @JonClements Regex should be last resort only.

Comment: Do you want 0.810 in the variable? As string or int? Is that missing a '='?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. From the docs, it will:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

So if you can take your `string`:

```
prue = "VA=-0.850,0.800;CA=-0.863,0.800;SP=-0.860,0.810;MO=-0.860,0.810;SUN=MO -0.850,CA 0.810"
```

you can do :

```
prue.split(",")
```

which will return a `list` of the `strings` `split` by the `commas`:

```
['VA=-0.850', '0.800;CA=-0.863', '0.800;SP=-0.860', '0.810;MO=-0.860', '0.810;SUN=MO -0.850', 'CA 0.810']
```

So if you just want the last `item` (`'CA 0.8101'`) into a `variable` named `test`, you can just take the last `element` from the `list` by `indexing` with `-1`:

```
test = prue.split(",")[-1]
```

*`test` is now: `'CA 0.810'`*

Hope this helps!